# Dapper.Contrib [Computed] Attribute does not allow property through on insert

Tags: git, ado.net, dapper, dapper-contrib

Let me start off by saying, this is in no way a criticism. Dapper is an incredible tool, which I'm extremely happy to use. Dapper.Contrib being no different.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the `[Computed]` attribute. But the documentation clearly states:

> ... this property is computed and should not be part of updates

Which leads me to believe the other operations, `SELECT/INSERT`, remain valid. And this is in fact true for `SELECT`

However, in looking at the [source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/071a3fd5a0e9a3ebb9b598737b94b49c56446722/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L332) it's clear that it's ignore on `INSERT` statements as well.

You can see in this [commit](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/commit/67026a0dd7468dbfc5a0dd21d9918c1db3be5290) that the code was clearly changed to ignore properties with the `[Computed]` attribute. But the title of the commit is misleading, insofar that it seems like it means to **allow** computed properties on `INSERT`.

I guess my question is, are we looking at an instance of outdated documentation? Or, should computed properties be pushed through on `INSERT`'s and this was a faulty commit?